# ActiveRecord "where" query using join table method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, has-many-through, model-associations

I have the following models: Project, Developer, and Topic. I also have some join tables: ProjectTopic and DeveloperTopic.

I want to be able to find all of the Developers who have the same topics as a given instance of a project. I can get the project's topics by doing Project.first.topics, but I can't do a Developer.where query using the topic column because it doesn't exist - it's just a method created through the join table/through association.

How can I find all of the developers who also have the same topic(s) as a given project?

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :developer_technologies
  has_many :technologies, through: :developer_technologies
  has_many :developer_topics
  has_many :topics, through: :developer_topics

end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :technologies, through: :project_technologies
  has_many   :topics, through: :project_topics
  has_many   :project_technologies
  has_many   :project_topics
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :developer

end

class ProjectTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :topic
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :developers
  has_many :developer_technologies, through: :developers
  has_many :projects
  has_many :project_technologies, through: :project

end

class DeveloperTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure about this, but it's worth a try:

```
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
def find_whatever(project)
    includes(:topic).where("topics.project_id" => project.topics_ids)
end
```

You'll need to delegate topics_ids to project.

Answer (score 0):

If a project has topics [A, B, C], and a developer has topics [C, D, E], does that count as what you're looking for since they both share topic C? Or do you mean that the developer has to have exactly [A, B, C] and possibly some other topics?

If you want the first case, then I think you should be able to get the developers associated with each topic by first doing Project.first.topics.includes(:developers). And then some how merge the developers into a list.

Note that in your topics model, you should probably be connecting to the developers table through the DeveloperTopic join table you have instead of doing it directly .

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by iterating through all developers and calling .topics on each, then checking it against the project's topics, and if it was a match, pushing the developer to an array.

Comment: You can also do this directly through your query, making the database return only the needed data, and making your app as light-weight as possible.